# C# List of Lists capacities

Tags: c#, list

How can I set the capacity of  `new List<List<Brick>>();`,  to be (10,12) ?

Something like this does not compile: `List<new List<Brick>(10)>(12);` and I did not find anything related to this when I searched.

Comment: Why are you setting the initial capacities of a dynamically sized list?

Comment: @THBBFT Because it is more efficient to do that when i know the List will have a exactly  (10,12) items to be added at max ? (since the `resize list event` will never occur)

Comment: you will have to initialize the inner list independently first and pass it to the outer list.

Comment: @Shiro in this case why do you not creating matrix?

Comment: @Denis because i will need the functions of `List` class

Comment: @THBBFT  `List<Brick> inner = new List<Brick>(10);`   `Bricks = new List<inner>(12);`   this does not seem to work, what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: @Denis The List<list<Brick>> is not a rectangular array.  All the constructor would do is set the capacity of the first item.

Comment: @Shiro: Which functions of `List` do you think you need? Because most of the collection classes implement that same handful of interfaces and their maybe a more suitable choice than `List<List<T>>` if you explained exactly what you need. Either way, I wouldn't worry about resizing events unless your profile your code and identify it as a bottleneck.

Comment: @Thbbft actually, it is a rectangular array (array of arrays), it just can only be accessed via the List api and only the populated extents may be accessed.

Comment: @MichaelPetito Regardless of the initialized capacities, the `List<T>` remains and it is dynamically sized.  So even if the initial capacities are all equal there is nothing stopping the addition (or removal) of additional elements into the inner generic `List<T>`.  Making this a jagged array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the capacity of a list when you construct it.

First you would create your outer list with its capacity of 12 by specifying the capacity in its constructor.

Then, loop through and add 12 lists of capacity 10 to your outer list.

If your outer list may contain some number of lists < 12, then you just have to make sure each time you add a new inner list you specify its capacity too.

Edit: the declaration for your outer list should be:

`List<List<Brick>> outer = new List<List<Brick>>(12);`

Comment: (kind of irrelevant question): is it possible to use `Brick[i][j]`  to refference the (i,j) Brick ? because it does not seem like i can, it says out of range exception even on dynamic capaticy List of Lists

Comment: @Shiro Yes, that's how you would do it. You're getting the exception because you've only set the capacity....you haven't added anything to the inner lists.

Comment: Yes, you can so long as your indicies are within the range of the outer and inner lists respectively. Note, however, that you cannot access an index greater than a lists `Count`, even if it is within the list's `Capacity`.

Comment: @Kaz            ` Bricks = new List<List<Brick>>();  Bricks[0][0] = new Brick();`    this does not work i get an out of range exception, any idea why that is ?

Comment: It's out of range because your lists are empty. See my comment about Capacity vs Count.

Comment: @Shiro Because there's nothing in your list of lists.

Comment: @Kaz yes, i am trying to add a `new Brick()` to the (0,0) slot of my List of Lists, how would i do that ? that was the question i was asking in the comments, sorry if it was not clear

Comment: You'll have to use the `Add` method to add the initial elements to your lists, including adding the inner lists.

Comment: @Shiro You would do something like this `Bricks[0].Add(new Brick());`

Comment: @Kaz you can only do that if the outer list also contains at least one inner list. Otherwise your indexer will still be out of range.

Comment: @MichaelPetito Well yeah.....The snippet is assuming the inner lists are already allocated.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<Brick>> bricks = new List<List<Brick>>{
    new List<Brick>(12),
    new List<Brick>(12),
    new List<Brick>(12),
    // ...
    new List<Brick>(12),
};
```

Comment: Exactly what i started to add.  Thanks @Denis

Comment: This could be better with a `foreach`. What if they need 100 lists?

Comment: It's just example. If will be 100 lists, `for` will be more good approach.